How much harassment, bigotry or abuse can a user engage in before facing consequences?
Over the past few days I have raised approximately 10 "helpful" flags on a single user for "harassment, bigotry and abuse". I can't be sure of the exact number, because there were some similar posts from another user that I also flagged. I have raised other helpful flags against this user in the past and I also know that this user has a pattern of similar behaviour, since I previously noticed that they had been suspended for 1 month.
Despite all this, there do not appear to have been any negative consequences for the user in question. As an aside I would note that I have seen other users, apparently guilty of far less, who incurred very lengthy bans. I doubt moderators can provide a precise quantification of offenses vs punishment (and even if they could there is some argument for retaining some ambiguity), however perhaps they could clarify what sort of factors go into deciding what action to take against someone who persistently engages in activity against the code of conduct?

While not a full answer to the question, I'm pretty sure that moderators perform actions based on judgement and not precedent. In fact I'm not sure there is coordination at all between moderators for these type of issues so I doubt this question is even answerable.

Some moderators seem to act extraordinary reasonably. Still your question is downvoted to the ground, which might point to a problem in this community.

I would note that you can flag a comment for bigotry and a moderator could remove it for another reason.  That would rate as helpful and the comment would be gone, but the mod many not quite have seen the need to take things any further.  i.e. your perception of bigotry isn't necessarily proven correct by any one comment's removal.  However a recurring pattern of near-unfriendly comments might need more attention than just treating them in isolation.
